# why are these integrals equal?

Tags: geometry, integration, symmetry

I've been trying to analyse Steiner symmetrization. I've asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354466/steiner-symmetrization-preserves-area) about the symmetrization preserving $\textit{volume}$, I'm still going over the same proof. I think I understand a bit what is going on.

I have one issue however, the [slides](http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Steiner/SteinerSlides.pdf) I'm going through state that:

$\int_{x_n \in G_x \cap \Omega}dx_n = m(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0) = \int_{x_n \in G_x \cap S(\Omega)}dx_n$

Can someone please take a peek at the [slides](http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Steiner/SteinerSlides.pdf) and explain if you can.

I think I understand why $\int_{x_n \in G_x \cap \Omega}dx_n = m(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)$. It is sayin' that the result is just function of the other variables without $x_n$, the variable we were integrating with respect to.

What I do agree with is that
         $\int_{x_n \in G_x \cap \Omega}dx_n = m_1(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)$ and $\int_{x_n \in G_x \cap S(\Omega)}dx_n = m_2(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)$. Why is $m_2(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0) = m_1(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)$ though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to think over what they're saying. For each value of $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$, the Steiner symmetrization is the map that sends the slice of $\Omega$ with those values to the interval of the *same length* as the slice, centered about the origin.

All your integral says is that the measure of the slice is the measure of the same slice on the Steiner-symmmetrized set, which is just true by the way the symmetrization was defined.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thanks Ray!