# Why Steiner Symmetrization makes a measurable set to a measurable one?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I find the Steiner Symmetrization is very useful in proving that the Hausdorff measure coincide with Lebesgue in the Euclidean space. However, I never saw anybody mention that the Steiner Symmetrization takes a measurable set to a measurable one. To know how this is done, see [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Steiner/SteinerSlides.pdf).

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354466/steiner-symmetrization-preserves-area) is also a related problem.

Comment: This is shown, for example, in 'Evans, Gariepy; Measure theory and fine properties of functions', on page 67 for Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I will read that book then.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, I'll sketch the proof in the book by Evans and  Gariepy that [Thomas mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696107/why-steiner-symmetrization-makes-a-measurable-set-to-a-measurable-one#comment1458458_696107). Let's consider symmetrization in the direction of the vector $e_n=(0,0,\dots, 1)$. 
Let $A^*$ be the Steiner symmetrization of $A$. So, the lines used in the symmetrization process are of the form $L_b =\{b+te_n :t\in\mathbb{R}\} $  where $b\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Since the characteristic function $\chi_A$ is measurable, by Fubuni-Tonelli theorem the function $f(b) = \int_{L_b}\chi_A d\mathcal L^1$ is measurable with respect to the $(n-1)$-dimensional measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. The set $A^*$ is bounded between two copies of the graph of $\frac12 f$. It remains to observe that for a measurable $g$, the set 
$$
\{x:x_n < g(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) \}
$$
is measurable, being the pre-image of open half-space under the measurable map $x\mapsto x - g(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})e_n$.